# Постраничный вывод

Tags: c

Вводятся значения: начальное x1 и конечное x2 с шагом dx

> `x1       f
> x1+dx    f
> x1+dx+dx f`

и так далее. Выводится вся информация сразу в виде таблицы. А как организовать постраничный вывод, например, по 10 значений? Вот вывело 10 строк, далее нажал клавишу еще 10 строк и так далее.

```
for (x = X1; x <= X2; x += dX) {
    if ((x < 0) && (b != 0)) {
        if (10 + b == 0) {
            printf("| %0.2f |error|n", x);
        } else {
            F = a - (x / (10 + b));        //pow âîçâåäåíèå â ñòåïåíü
            printf("| %0.2f | %0.2f |n", x, F);
        }
    } else {
        if ((x > 0) && (b == 0)) {
            if ((x - c) == 0) {
                printf("| %0.2f |error|n", x);
            } else {
                F = (x - a) / (x - c);
                printf("| %0.2f | %0.2f |n", x, F);
            }
        } else {
            if (c == 0) {
                printf("| %0.2f |error|n", x, F);
            } else {
                F = 3 * x + 2 / c;
                printf("| %0.2f | %0.2f |n", x, F);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Добавляем дополнительную переменную-счетчик с начальным значением 0, каждую итерацию цикла увеличиваем его на единицу. Как только становится = 10, выводим сообщение "нажмите любую клавишу для продолжения" и ждем нажатия клавиши. Клавиша нажата - обнуляем счетчик и продолжаем.

Comment: Можете в коде какой нибудь пример написать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <conio.h>

for (x = X1, i=0; x <= X2; x += dX, i++) {
    if(i==10) {
        puts("Press any key...");
        _getch();
        i=0;
    }

    // остальная часть цикла
}
```

Comment: @insolor@insolor, 
ПАсиб

Comment: @wapdimon72ru, лучшая благодарность - принять ответ :)